# Invalid result dendogram

Tags: dataframe, error-handling

I want to make a dendrogram for clustering morphological characters.
i put this

```
plot(hirarkisingle,data1$Spesimen, labels=data1$Spesimen)
```

but an error appears as follows

```
Error in graphics:::plotHclust(n1, merge, height, order(x$order), hang,  : 
  invalid dendrogram input
In addition: Warning message:
In graphics:::plotHclust(n1, merge, height, order(x$order), hang,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

please help and the solution for this, thank you

I want to see some groups of dendrograms to see the fenetic / filogenetic kinship between populations from my morphological character data.